# Angular material - applying error-class is delayed when manually set error on input

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, ng-messages

I have a username input and I have a custom error message "*Username already taken*" via **ng-messages**. I managed to manually add and show the error message but the problem is the "error-class"(or something that turns the angular-material input into color red on error) is some kind of "*delayed*". I set the error then the error message shows but there is no error-class applied. I changed the username value(this will set the error to false based on my custom function) then the error message disappears but the error-class is applied just this time.

To show you what my problem is, heres a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ldio7gHE9oAONqpRGfli?p=preview)

***--EDIT--***

Someone gave me and idea, and I just have to manually set the error-class on input, but in angular-material's own way. Just put md-is-error on md-input-container and also to manually set input's validity in controller

```
<md-input-container md-is-error="sampleForm.userName.$invalid">
```

Heres an updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ldio7gHE9oAONqpRGfli?p=preview)

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your plunkr works just fine?

Comment: It shows the error, but the "error-class"(red line and labels on userName input) is not applied immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Its working, See the plunker
  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/smneDRsgO6rYnOGVKBWe)

Use ng-class to dynamically add 'errorClass' to the input box

**`ng-class="{'errorClass': sampleForm.userName.$error.alreadyTaken}"`**

I have added .errorClass when the $error gets true.

write 'alexpogi' in username field which makes the content red

Comment: your solution is working just fine but angular material's error class turns the input's border and label into red, not the text. I see that the problem is on angular-material. I wonder if angular-material has a builtin or more proper way of handling this problem.